# Compiling Riofs, can't compile with support to --force-head-requests

Tags: debian, compiling

I am on Debian Jessie, compiling the last master with a gcc 4.8 and some higher versions for some of the required libs, required libs are :

```
glib >= 2.22
fuse >= 2.7.3
libevent >= 2.0
libxml >= 2.6
libcrypto >= 0.9
libmagic (optional: --with-libmagic=PATH)
```

Everything goes smooth, configure stage drops no error, neither make. But I can't use --force-head-requests because it is not compiled in to the binary ( the option does not show when executing the binary --help )

When trying to make a symlink after mounting the bucket, I get failed to create symbolic link function not implemented. This is the project in github : https://github.com/skoobe/riofs

Is this some backward lib incompatibility issue ?

Comment: Run `./configure --help` and read the output carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install the dev package for `libmagic-dev`:

```
apt-get install libmagic-dev
```

Then point the `--configure` to the location `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmagic.so`

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local  --with-libmagic=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
checking magic.h usability... yes
checking magic.h presence... yes
checking for magic.h... yes
checking for magic_open in -lmagic... yes
```